# Preserve Requested Protocol in Sub-Directory with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, protocols

We have a http > https redirect on our 'top' level:

```
example.com/top/
```

Now for a sub-directory of /top/:

```
example.com/top/sub/
```

I want to preserve whatever protocol is requested there.

So if it's http://example.com/top/sub/this.php I want it to stay as 'http'

And if it's https://example.com/top/sub/this.php I want it to stay as 'https'

Currently I have an .htaccess file in the /top/sub/ directory with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,END]
```

Which is doing exactly what I need it to be doing, so in terms of all the requests being sent to the sub-directory it's perfect.

The issue is I'm getting an error message in the error_log reporting this:

```
[REWRITE] detected external loop redirection with target URL: http://example.com/top/sub/this.php, skip.
```

I understand why I'm getting this message, because every time a HTTP request is made it's matching this condition, I just don't know how to stop it. I tried using the 'END' parameter to force only one redirect - but this doesn't seem to be working, or at least not working the way I expected it to.

All I want is for the protocol to remain the same as requested for /top/sub/ - the issue is the /top/ redirect sending everything to HTTPS.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested to know if there is actually a way to preserve a protocol without creating a loop, however I was able to achieve what I was after by just adjusting the redirect in /top/ to only redirect pages that didn't match /top/sub/ - I really should have thought of that as a solution earlier.

Hope that can help someone.